# Redirect to action when validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Good Afternoon All,

I'm trying to figure out how I can stop a user from leaving the edit page, including clicking on other links until the user.valid?

Does anyone know of a way to do this in the model. Just for reference here is the model currently with the validations.

```
  #validations for common attributes

     validates :email, presence: true, on: :create, uniqueness: true,
               :format => /@/
     validates :password, presence: true, on: :create, length: {minimum: 6}

     #validations blocks for dev

    with_options :if => lambda { |o| o.role_type == "developer" } do |dev|
      dev.validates :first_name, presence: true, on: :update
      dev.validates :last_name, presence: true, on: :update
      dev.validates :LANGUAGES, presence: true, on: :update
      dev.validates :dev_desc, presence: true, on: :update
      dev.validates :github, presence: true, on: :update, 
                    :format => URI::regexp(%w(http https github))
      dev.validates :stackoverflow, presence: true, on: :update, 
                    :format => URI::regexp(%w(http https stackoverflow))
      dev.validates :level, presence: true, on: :update
       dev.validates :street, presence: true, on: :update
       dev.validates :city, presence: true, on: :update
       dev.validates :state, presence: true, on: :update
       dev.validates :postcode, presence: true, on: :update
    end

    #validations block for employer

    with_options :if => lambda { |o| o.role_type == "employer" } do |e|
        e.validates :company_name, presence: true, on: :update,
                    uniqueness: true
        e.validates :employer_desc, presence: true, on: :update
        e.validates :area_of_focus, presence: true, on: :update
        e.validates :number_of_employees, presence: true, on: :update
     e.validates :street, presence: true, on: :update
     e.validates :city, presence: true, on: :update
     e.validates :state, presence: true, on: :update
     e.validates :postcode, presence: true, on: :update
    end
```

Maybe a after_validation hook but I'm not to sure, would like some advise.

**UPDATE:** Tried using the below in the application controller but hooks to all pages, how would I only assigned the method for the user.

```
  def check_valid
    if current_user.valid? == false 
       render :action => :edit
       else
      jobs_path
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok in order to solved this, I took the idea mentioned by @dosadnizub and placed it in my application controller as such.

```
def check_privileges!
  redirect_to "/users/edit" unless current_user.valid?
end
```

I then used it in the relevant controllers to stop users escaping the edit page. Haven't fully tested it but works well for now:

```
 before_filter :check_privileges!, only: [:new, :create]
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is that when member enters the edit page you set a variable in his session that says `member_on_edit = true` and you need to submit the form through JS on change of any element of the edit form and store current form state into the session.

This will enable you to put a `before_filter` in `ApplicationController` that redirects the member to the edit page and populates the form elements with data stored in session.

Once session'd form state is valid and member clicks 'submit' you can set `member_on_edit = false` and prevent further undue redirects to the edit form.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail, I'm not good with JS yet is there maybe I a way I could do this without using JS,

Comment: As you can noticed, JS is sugar on top, you can do without it if you're happy with the result :)